# C++ common way to get overloaded member function pointer

Tags: c++

What is the common way of getting the address of an overloaded member function (real member and static member with alternative calling convention)?
The following example fails in case of alternative calling convention:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


struct A {
    int mem(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    };
    int mem(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    static int stat(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    }
    static int stat(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};


int main() {
    A a;

    cout << "a.mem(1) -> " << a.mem(1) << endl;
    cout << "a.mem(1, 2) -> " << a.mem(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << "A::stat(1) -> " << A::stat(1) << endl;
    cout << "A::stat(1, 2) -> " << A::stat(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << "a.stat(1) -> " << a.stat(1) << endl;
    cout << "a.stat(1, 2) -> " << a.stat(1, 2) << endl;

    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;

    auto aMem1 = static_cast<int(A::*)(int)>(&A::mem);
    cout << "a.*aMem1(1) -> " << (a.*aMem1)(1) << endl;
    auto aMem2 = static_cast<int(A::*)(int, int)>(&A::mem);
    cout << "a.*aMem2(1, 2) -> " << (a.*aMem2)(1, 2) << endl;
    auto stat1 = static_cast<int(*)(int)>(&A::stat);
    cout << "stat1(1) -> " << stat1(1) << endl;
    auto stat2 = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(&A::stat);
    cout << "stat2(1, 2) -> " << stat2(1, 2) << endl;
    // these fail:
    auto aStat1 = static_cast<int(A::*)(int)>(&A::stat);
    cout << "a.*aStat1(1) -> " << (a.*aStat1)(1) << endl;
    auto aStat2 = static_cast<int(A::*)(int, int)>(&A::stat);
    cout << "a.*aStat2(1, 2) -> " << (a.*aStat2)(1, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

See [live](http://cpp.sh/8lzmo) example.

Background:
I do not know if the implementation uses member functions or static member functions, therefore, I need a common way to handle both. The obvious way was not successful, as seen above.

Comment: `stat` can be addressed via a member function pointer if it is not overloaded.

Comment: No it may not http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2198b752c20bdc1a

Comment: Please elaborate on the context that requires you to treat both static and non-static members uniformally. There may be a way to solve *that* problem without having to do something intractable.

Comment: "I do not know if the implementation uses member functions or static member functions". You cannot get away not knowing this.

Comment: How about using lambda ? `[](A&a, int i1, int i2){ a.stat(i1, i2);}`.

Comment: Arduino API documents libraries like SPI with member functions. The implementation, however, often uses static member functions if there is at most one instance depending on the target. This is transparent for most of the users, because they can use the alternative calling convention for static member functions as seen on OP code line 30 `a.stat(1)` and 31 `a.stat(1, 2)`.

Comment: So is the only way to get around this to use a proxy function or class which calls the member function in question?

Comment: Do you need to take an address of a member function of a class in one of the Arduino's libraries, and pass it to another function?

Comment: Correct, that is exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Then the interface of the *other* function determines what you need to pass in. I assume the other function will not accept pointers to members. It is very rarely the right thing to do. So if the other function expects an `int (*)()`, you simply cannot pass it an `int (A::*)()`. You also cannot convert between these things. Overloading is a red herring here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to be able to treat the expression `&A::x` in the same way regardless of whether `x` is a static or non-static member of `A` (and it might be overloaded) then you need to pass it through some other overloaded function that can accept either `R(C::*)(Ts...)` or `R(C::*)(Ts...)const` or `R(*)(Ts...)` and dispatch accordingly. Something like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct UniformResolver {
    template <typename C, typename R>
    constexpr auto operator()(R (C::*func)(Ts...)) const { return resolveMember(func); }
    template <typename C, typename R>
    constexpr auto operator()(R (C::*func)(Ts...) const) const { return resolveMember(func); }
    template <typename R>
    constexpr auto operator()(R (*func)(Ts...)) const { return resolveStatic(func); }
private:
    template <typename F>
    constexpr auto resolveMember(F func) const {
        return [func](auto&&... args) {
            return std::invoke(func, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };
    }
    template <typename F>
    constexpr auto resolveStatic(F func) const {
        return [func](auto&&, auto&&... args) {
            return std::invoke(func, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        };
    }
};
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr UniformResolver<Ts...> uresolve {};
```

This gives you a callable object template `uresolve` that adapts your function pointer, returning a callable object that can be called in a uniform way and that delegates to your function pointer. This is how you would use it:

```
struct A {
    int mem(int a) const { return a * 2; }
    int mem(int a, int b) const { return a + b; }
    static int stat(int a) { return a * 2; }
    static int stat(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    auto mem1 = uresolve<int>(&A::mem);
    auto mem2 = uresolve<int, int>(&A::mem);
    auto stat1 = uresolve<int>(&A::stat);
    auto stat2 = uresolve<int, int>(&A::stat);

    std::cout << mem1(a, 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << mem2(a, 1, 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << stat1(a, 1) << '\n';
    std::cout << stat2(a, 1, 2) << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ff3098272d8309)

Answer (score 0):

To allow functions with similar declarations to be stored in a single variable [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) can be used.

A function with a single parameter:

```
std::function< int(int) > func_1_param;

func_1_param = static_cast< int (*)(int) >(&A::stat);
cout << "int(int)->" << func_1_param(1) << endl;

using  std::placeholders::_1;

func_1_param = std::bind(static_cast< int (A::*)(int) >(&A::mem), &a, _1);
cout << "int(int)->" << func_1_param(1) << endl;
```

Function with 2 parameters;

```
std::function< int(int, int) > func_2_param;

func_2_param = static_cast< int (*)(int, int) >(&A::stat);
cout << "int(int, int)->" << func_2_param(1, 2) << endl;

using  std::placeholders::_1;
using  std::placeholders::_2;

func_2_param = std::bind(static_cast< int (A::*)(int, int) >(&A::mem), &a, _1, _2);
cout << "int(int, int)->" << func_2_param(1, 2) << endl;
```

Instead of using `std::bind`, a lambda can be used.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer the question nor solves the issue from the given background information.

Comment: Please explain why it doesn't solve the issue? This answer presents a solution how to handle both member functions and static functions as 1.

Comment: You show how to handle both cases, static and non-static member functions but you are not using one common way to get the right overload from the member functions (be it static or non-static). I do not know beforehand, if the class implements the member function static or non-static.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no way to cast the static member function into a member function pointer to resolve the overload in a generic way nor any other direct approach.
Picking up the hint from Jarod42 gives the following solution with indirection via some proxy class, function or in this case lambda (as long as it is non-capturing):

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


struct A {
    int mem(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    };
    int mem(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    static int stat(int a) {
        return a * 2;
    }
    static int stat(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};


static A a;


int main() {
    typedef int(*type1)(int);
    typedef int(*type2)(int, int);

    cout << "a.mem(1) -> " << a.mem(1) << endl;
    cout << "a.mem(1, 2) -> " << a.mem(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << "A::stat(1) -> " << A::stat(1) << endl;
    cout << "A::stat(1, 2) -> " << A::stat(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << "a.stat(1) -> " << a.stat(1) << endl;
    cout << "a.stat(1, 2) -> " << a.stat(1, 2) << endl;

    cout << "----------------------------------" << endl;

    type1 aMem1 = [] (int a0) -> int { return a.mem(a0); };
    cout << "aMem1(1) -> " << aMem1(1) << endl;
    type2 aMem2 = [] (int a0, int a1) -> int { return a.mem(a0, a1); };
    cout << "aMem2(1, 2) -> " << aMem2(1, 2) << endl;
    type1 stat1 = [] (int a0) -> int { return A::stat(a0); };
    cout << "stat1(1) -> " << stat1(1) << endl;
    type2 stat2 = [] (int a0, int a1) -> int { return A::stat(a0, a1); };
    cout << "stat2(1, 2) -> " << stat2(1, 2) << endl;
    type1 aStat1 = [] (int a0) -> int { return a.stat(a0); };
    cout << "aStat1(1) -> " << aStat1(1) << endl;
    type2 aStat2 = [] (int a0, int a1) -> int { return a.stat(a0, a1); };
    cout << "aStat2(1, 2) -> " << aStat2(1, 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

See [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c155d81b1143d2f) example.

This leverages the original issue by using the same calling convention as enforced to the user. This means that if the user is able to call the member function (be it static or not) in such way, we are also because we are using the same calling convention. One could keep using member function pointers by using a proxy class instead. For me the lambda approach worked better.